# Removable singularity of $|z|^\alpha$ and its fourier transform

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

The idea that $|z|^\alpha$ for $\alpha \in (-1,0)$ has a removable singularity seems somewhat draconian.  But by the proof of Riemann's theorem,

since we have $\lim_{|z| \to 0} |z \times z^\alpha|=\lim_{r \to 0} |re^{i\theta} \times r^\alpha|=\lim_{r \to 0} r^{1-\alpha}=0$, it must be true that $|z|^\alpha$ has a removable singularity.

My aim in all this is to find the fourier transform of $|x|^\alpha$.  If $|z|^\alpha$ has a removable singularity, then how is one supposed to use residue theorem to find the foureir transform of $|x|^\alpha$?

Comment: A function $f$ which is holomorphic in a punctured disk centered at $0$ has a removable singularity iff $f(z)$ is bounded near $0$. But you don't have a function which is holomorphic in a punctured disk. You have a function that requires a branch cut when considered in such a disk.

Comment: @T.A.E. Is there any way to see that it needs a branch cut? It seems that there are no branch points.  At 0, when traversing an loop around the origin, $|re^{i\theta}|^\alpha \to |re^{i \theta+2 \pi i}|=r^\alpha=|re^{i\theta}|^\alpha$.  This holds both for arbitrarily small loops and arbitrarily large loops so there can't be any branch points any where.

Comment: $|z|^{\alpha}$ is not holomorphic.